# NSPredicate core data, fetch some objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity, ProductCart & Cart, with a to many relationship. ProductCart has an attribute called ordered, which determine if the product has been ordered. Now I want to fetch all the objects in ProductCart which has'nt been ordered. Have tried something like this but it does not work:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =  [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ProductCart"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inCart == %@ && !ordered == %@", cart, [self valueForKey:@"ordered"]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =  [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"products.name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

inCart fetches the relationship, ordered is giving me problems. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `ordered` a boolean attribute? Is this predicate always used for things which haven't been ordered?

Comment: Yes it is a boolean attribute :)... No, also when is has been ordered, but for this I use another fetchrequest and predicate :)

Answer (score 0):

I expect your predicate should be more like:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inCart == %@ && ordered == NO", cart];
```

because you just want to test the state of `ordered` rather than trying to compare it to some other value.